# Entries from previous year 2016 not displaying

Tags: search, entries-field, bug

Ok, so this is pretty bizarre... Entries from 2016 are NOT displaying when searched for in the admin panel. Whether we search by the year, title, or part of the title<strike>, until they're edited (using the id to access them)</strike>.

I see entries from 2015 and 2017 but only a few from 2016 which<strike>, as I said, are the ones we managed to edit</strike>.

This happens in the list of entries as well as on fields that link to them and we've got LOTS of entries...

UPDATE - Check this out:

- Articles listed from December 2016:
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/o0rmkiazm436etb/Screenshot%202017-10-22%2009.16.07.png
- Searching for name of article:
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/ydwilwz6pye1jb4/Screenshot%202017-10-22%2009.16.44.png
- Searching for year 2016, bottom of results, all 2015 and 2017:
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/w7imwnnfyrnjjri/Screenshot%202017-10-22%2009.17.15.png
- If i access the article highlighted on screenshot 1, via URL:
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/opdv12hpyz993z4/Screenshot%202017-10-22%2009.20.50.png

The articles are there, they're accessible from the user end, but for some reason they won't show up on the Admin side. Bizarre...

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing and where you're seeing it?

Comment: @BradBell, I've added screenshots that hopefully help explain the whole deal. Thanks!

Comment: Do they show up if you sort by post date instead of score (Puntuacion)? What happens if you search for part of the title (e.g. "Helicópteros")?

Comment: @phaetons Ah, I think I had a screenshot of that too. Even searching by part of the title wouldn't get them to show up. I'll try to upload that when I get to the office. I'll try sorting by date and see what happens.

Comment: @phaetons, ok, sorted by date and scrolling to 2016 does show the articles. Which I guess it means it has more to do with the search than the articles themselves. The problem is that with so many entries, it takes about 5 mins to get to the ones from 2016. 
I also tried your suggestion of looking for a word in the title with no positive results.

Comment: like @carlcs posted, "rebuild search index" could be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your search indexes are corrupted. I’d try to run the “Rebuild Search Indexes” tool in CP > Settings.

Comment: It looks like it crashed my server... I'm just realizing that there may be some performance issues behind all this. The Stalled Tasks button is always there which at first I didn't quite understand so I ignored. I posted that as a separate question, since it seemed appropriate: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/22551/whats-the-function-of-the-stalled-tasks-menu-option

Comment: Is there a way to see if Rebuild Search Indexes is still running in the background? I think MySQL is using over 1Gb of memory... (using htop)

Comment: @cballenar no wonder you’re having issues with search! That one stuck task stopped all other queued tasks from being processed, and I bet you updated entries in the meantime.

Comment: I sure did, carlcs... I'm ashamed of admitting that the Stalled Tasks button has been there for A WHILE... I just thought it was some cool new feature (not a warning!) and I never bothered to look into it since I had this project in the back burner. Working on it now though!