# What's the function of the Stalled Tasks menu option?

Tags: admin, stalled-tasks

Just wondering...

- What is the function of the Stalled Tasks menu option?
- What is it supposed to do when clicking on it?
- Is it normal for it to be there... all the time?
- Is it normal for the browser to freeze when I click on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the function of the Stalled Tasks menu option?

To let you know there is currently a stalled task, to show all of the subsequent tasks that stalled task is blocking and in some scenarios, give you a chance to restart the task.

> What is it supposed to do when clicking on it?

Show a modal with the stalled task and (potentially) other tasks that it is blocking.

> Is it normal for it to be there... all the time?

Nope. The underlying reason that task stalled should be debugged and fixed. https://craftcms.com/support/stuck-tasks

> Is it normal for the browser to freeze when I click on it?

Nope.

Comment: Thanks Brad! For some reason it wasn't very obvious until just now 